# Can I lazy-bind @Named dependencies?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to register a handler with Guice that is called when a @Named dependency is not found?

I could then look up missing bindings in the application's configuration file at runtime; otherwise I'd need to pre-bind all properties as Strings.

Comment: Pre-binding all your properties seems like it'd be more stable in the long term, no? A missing binding is a configuration error and should rightfully prevent your injector from starting up (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). What exactly is your goal in trying to recover from missing bindings? In general, Guice doesn't provide a fallback for configuration errors, but there may be another way to approach this.

Comment: The injector will fail in either case (assuming the managed objects are instantiated eagerly). I'd like to be able to get properties from a framework-specific configuration file without having to iterate through all the properties. Also, because the configuration format is hierarchical, a "mail.host" and "mail.port" setting might get injected as a single "mail" property--or not. Looking up properties by name is trivial; anticipating which properties could be used and how, not.

Comment: To clarify, let me take a step back and ask: what's the main goal you're trying to accomplish? Is it that you want to be able to, for example, make changes to the properties file and verify that those changes don't break your current Guice bindings and deps? Also, are you using `Names.bindProperties(...)`? (see http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Names.html)

Comment: I'm trying to read properties from the configuration file for a Play 2.x application. The configuration file format is not a simple properties file; it is accessed through an API. The current solution requires an explicit list of properties I need to get for Guice; I'd rather have Guice tell me what @Names properties it is looking for.